# How to auto generate WSDL File using HTTPBinding

Tags: java, http, binding, wsdl

I am new to Web services . I tried an example given over here

**https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jws/jax-ws-hello-world-example-rpc-style/**

Here when i deploy the web app on tomcat, it opens a web page, clicking  on that it is directed to `WSDL`. Here  i have created  Java stub classes and `WSDL` is created on the fly. Similar thing i tried to do  for  another Web service But here using `HTTPBinding` . But i see `WSDL` is not published .

I tried in many ways , but  no success .

Below is the Impl class that i  created

```
@WebServiceProvider()
@ServiceMode(value=Service.Mode.MESSAGE)
@BindingType(value = HTTPBinding.HTTP_BINDING) 

public class WebServiceImpl implements Provider<Source> {
public Source invoke(Source source) {
try {
   return new StreamSource( new ByteArrayInputStream(printMessage().getBytes()));
} catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   throw new RuntimeException("Error in provider endpoint", e);
}
}
public String printMessage() {
String body= "Hello , Congratulations to  learn  HTTP Binding .happy learning!";
return body;
}
```

But I do neither get Webservice result on URL `localhost:8080/HttpWS/sayhello` nor `WSDL` link , like it  was shown in SOAP example .

Can some one please help me  in understanding how to  use `HTTPBinding` ?

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: After modifying  tag  @WebServiceProvider( 
  portName = "WebServiceImplPort",
     serviceName = "WebServiceImplService",
     targetNamespace = "http://jaxws.webservices.examples/",
     wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8080/HttpWS/sayhello?wsdl" ) I am getting below XML<ns:printMessageResponse xmlns:ns="http://duke.example.org">
<ns:return>Hello , Congratulations to learn HTTP Binding .happy learning </ns:return></ns:printMessageResponse> on accessing URL http://localhost:8080/HttpWS/sayhello  .         But what is the resultant  WSDL is still unanswered .  Please help .

Answer (score 0):

- I tried to use wsgen tool to create WSDL file for the above 
  WebService . But it gave message " wsgen can not generate WSDL for
  non-SOAP binding: http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl /http on Class
  com.pkg.WbServeImpl" I think that is why Eclipse is also not
  generating WSDL while my webservice up and running.For HTTP Binding 
  one has to manually write  and publish WSDL.       - Thanks